# Why is this async/Promise method running synchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml-parsing

I'm really a noob in JavaScript and I'm trying to write a small  ElectronJS/NodeJS app. I think the purpose of the App is not relevant to the question, suffice it to say that the App will listen to TCP connections that will send ~100MB of XML content and then will do some further processing on the parsed XML. Since the XML content is "large" the parsing is taking some time to process, so I decided to put the parsing in an asynchronous function but the code is apparently running synchronously. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if it's just because of the single-thread (AFAIU) nature of JavaScript.

```
var net = require('net');
const fs = require('fs');
const { XMLParser, XMLBuilder, XMLValidator} = require("fast-xml-parser");

const parser = new XMLParser();
var file_counter = 0;

var server = net.createServer(function(connection) { 
  console.log('Client Connected');

  var content = "";
   
  connection.on('data', function(data) {
    content += data.toString();
  });

  connection.on('end', async function() {
    console.log("client " + file_counter + " disconnected");

    saveObj(content, file_counter);

    console.log("returned from " + file_counter);
    file_counter++;
   });
   
   connection.write('y');
});

async function saveObj(data, cnt) {
  return new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => {
    let jObj = parser.parse(data);
    console.log("Parsed content number " + cnt);
  }, 1000));
}
```

The output that I get consistently is `Parsed content number 0, 1, 2...N.` Even though the size of "data" is quite different from one connection to another.

Comment: You never called `res()` inside your `setTimeout`?

Comment: In order for a `Promise` to resolve, you need to call `res()`, aka `resolve()` (the first callback parameter).

Comment: Like this: `async function saveObj(data, cnt) {
  return new Promise(res => { setTimeout(() => { let jObj = parser.parse(data); console.log("Parsed content number " + cnt); }, 1000); res(); });
}`

Comment: That looks correct. I added a response below.

Comment: `let jObj = parser.parse(data);`   Oh, hang on a min, are you saying the XML is that large this `.parse(data)` is taking a long time.  Right this is a classic example of were Node worker threads come to play -> https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are resolving the promise at the end of the `setTimeout` callback.

```js
async function saveObj(data, cnt) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const jObj = parser.parse(data); // This should be sync
      console.log("Parsed content number " + cnt); // Also sync
      resolve(); // Resolve the promise
    }, 1000)
  });
}
```

Also, make sure you `await` when calling it:

```js
await saveObj(content, file_counter);
```

Comment: It seems to still be synchronous. I'll keep testing and if I conclude it's asynchronous I'll mark your answer as Accepted. Thanks

Comment: I believe his -> `parser.parse(data);` is the bottleneck and will indeed be `sync`, sticking inside a promise wont help here.  The OP will want to use a Worker Thread to stop his main thread blocking.